# While loop logic flaw

Tags: java, list, while-loop, queue

The problem is as below:
Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers out of 1 ... n.

For example,
If n = 4 and k = 2, a solution is:

```
[
  [2,4],
  [3,4],
  [2,3],
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [1,4]
]
```

My Solution is:

```
public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {
    Deque<List<Integer>> queue = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(i);
        queue.add(list);
    }

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        List<Integer> list = queue.pollFirst();
        if (list.size() == k)
            result.add(list);
        else {
            for (int i = list.get(list.size() - 1) + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                list.add(i);
                queue.addLast(list);
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However the while loop goes into a infinite loop. I have no idea what's wrong with the logic. I traced it for a couple of times but still can't find the logic flaw in this code.

Comment: Could it be because your queue never becomes empty?

Comment: I traced it with n = 2 and k =2, and supposedly the queue should be empty.  But when I compile it, it still goes into a infinite loop.

Comment: looking at the body of the second `for` loop, it seems that you do have a wrong concept of object referencing. or say: when you add something to a list, then add that list into the queue, and then remove the element from the list again, then the list in the queue will also not have that element, because it is the same object. there is no copy of the list created when you add it into the queue. that should lead you to a solution. good luck! :-)

Comment: @hoijui So whenever I change the list, the added list into queue will also change?

Comment: yes, it is the same object. in java, object parameter passing to functions happens by reference (that is for all objects inheriting from `Object`, which is everything except int, float and the like). you would have to create a new list: `new ArrayList(list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding the same list instance to the queue multiple times, so when you write :

```
            list.add(i); // suppose that list had 1 element. After adding 1,
                         // it has two elements
            queue.addLast(list); // here you add the list with 2 elements to
                                 // the queue
            list.remove(list.size() - 1); // here you remove the added element
                                          // so the list you just added
                                          // to the queue has just 1 element
```

The list that you added to the queue remains with the original number of elements.

You should create a new List instance before adding it to the queue :

```
            list.add(i);
            queue.addLast(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

above while (!queue.isEmpty())  {} is always true